# Xcode: Switching between views

Tags: ios, view, tableview, switching

I want to be able to switch between views.
I have been writing some code, but it is not working?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    AlleRumViewController *allerum = [[AlleRumViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

    if ([[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"Alle rum"]) {    
        [self presentModalViewController:allerum animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Do any of you know how i can switch?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)goButtonPressed:(UIButton*) source {
YourNewViewController* someNameController = [[YourNewViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:someNameController animated:YES];
[someNameController release];
}
```

Comment: Of course in the case of TableViewController you can write this code to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.